# How to set up GUI testing automation on Ubuntu server

Tags: user-interface, testing, ui-automation, build-server

I want to set up automated testing of a GUI app (say Qt) on Ubuntu Server distribution (i.e. without phisical monitor and without window manager). How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GUI applications - particularly Qt-based ones- usually need *some* display to connect to. Otherwise they'll have problems rendering the GUI (e.g. fonts) and receive input (e.g. mouse).

The need for a physical display can be avoided through a virtual display however. See this [Squish Knowledge Base artcile](https://kb.froglogic.com/display/KB/Article+-+Using+Squish+on+headless+systems) for hints on the usage of Xvnc, X11vnc, Xvfb and Xnest.

Running a window manager on the virtual display is still recommended. It does not have to be a full desktop environment. A simple WM does. GUI toolkits are not necessarily prepared